# Copy a file from windows server to a linux server

Tags: linux, ssh, powershell

Can anyone help me copy a file from powershell from a windows server to a linux server which is using a ssh key ? Only thing that i found on the web is this code:

```
scp Filepathinwindows username@ubuntuserverip:linuxserverpath
```

But if i run this command, it requires a password, and i don't have a password for that linux server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like scp is not finding your private key in the default search locations and file names.   You can explicitly specify the key to use with the `-i /path/to/id_rsa` key file.

```
scp -i /path/to/key/file Filepathinwindows username@ubuntuserverip:linuxserverpath
```